# WindowsForm in AddIn-Toolbar

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, add-in, toolbar

Is there any possibility to add a little WindowsForms with a textbox to an AddIn-Toolbar?

In ArcGIS 9.3 I could easily add it to the Toolbar.cs like all the buttons ect with AddItem but how can I do this in ArcGIS 10?

What I want to do is looping throught features. Of course I have a NextFeature- and a PreviousFeature-Button. But I also want to give the possibility to go to a certain feature by entering the OID in a textbox.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a ComboBox with no items instead and do the go to OID action in the `OnEnter` event.